# Get Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child() error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I having some trouble with how to use a `Button` to access another activity with data from firebase. I'm just getting an error "Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()". But when I try in another activity with OnItemClick on a listview item it works. Why is that?

What I'm trying to do is: I have a activity with a listview that stores and get data from firebase. What I want is, if I click on one of the items in that listview I want a new activity with buttons, and these buttons will get me to another activity with a listview that are related to the first activity (related data). So the activity with the buttons are the same activity for every listview items i click on, like just a "dummy" activity. Is this possible?

Here is the code:

lvjobbinfo works fine, but add doesn't. I want lvjobbinfo and add to do the same.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etinfonavn;
ListView lvjobbinfo;
TextView tvjobbnavn;
Button add;

DatabaseReference databaseJOBBINFO;

List<Main> jobbinfo;

public static final String infonavn = "infonavn";
public static final String infoid = "infoid";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    databaseJOBBINFO = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Jobbinfo");


    lvjobbinfo = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvjobbinfo);


    lvjobbinfo.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            Main main = jobbinfo.get(i);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Notater.class);

            intent.putExtra(infoid, main.getInfoId());
            intent.putExtra(infonavn, main.getInfonavn());

            startActivity(intent);

            return true;


        }
    });

    tvjobbnavn = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvjobbnavn);
    etinfonavn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etinfonavn) ;
    add  = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent add = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Notater.class);
            startActivity(add);
        }
    });




    Intent intent = getIntent();

    jobbinfo = new ArrayList<>();


    String id = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbId);
    String navn = intent.getStringExtra(Jobbliste.jobbnavn);

    tvjobbnavn.setText(navn);

    databaseJOBBINFO = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Jobbinfo").child(id);




}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    databaseJOBBINFO.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            jobbinfo.clear();

            for (DataSnapshot infosnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                final Main main = infosnapshot.getValue(Main.class);
                jobbinfo.add(main);


                final listMain infolistadapter = new listMain(MainActivity.this, jobbinfo);

                lvjobbinfo.setAdapter(infolistadapter);

                infolistadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }




        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {




    }
});
```

Comment: The error message is telling you that something is wrong with your code at runtime.  Please edit the question to share that code.

Comment: The error indicates that you're passing `null` into a call to `child`. The only place where I see that in the code you shared is `child(id)`, so it looks like `id` is `null` there. Run the code in a debugger and put a breakpoint on that line to see why that is.

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen said about your `id` being null. Did you check it? Could you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response guys, I'm gonna check it out later today.

Comment: I tried debugging my app, but to be honest, I didn't understand so much of it. So can you help me with this? Why is it working with onItemclicklistener and not setonclicklistener?

Comment: This line is giving me trouble: `databaseNotater = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notater").child(id)`; When I erase .child(id) it works with a button, but then the database is not related to each other. So seems I have to use .child(id). Is there any solution to this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67449449/4828650